# 16X2 character LCD changes contract intermittently and doesn't work with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, character-lcd, hd44780

I've been following adafruits RPi tutorials (and bought their starter kit)

I had an [Sparkfun LCD Kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10054) lying around. (It has an HD44780 controller LCD, a 10K trimpot and a 16 pin male header)

I soldered the header to the LCD, not all that well. I followed the tutorial step by step. [This page](http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/wiring) has the wiring and I started bit by bit.

**Symptoms** : When I connected the trimpot and turned the knob a random bunch of boxes go dark and then they just  slowly lighten and disappear. Even when it happens is intermittent. Sometimes I turn the knob, nothing happens, sometimes it lights a few boxes and on their own they dim out.

**Below** is what is looks like.

[This is the schematic](http://learn.adafruit.com/assets/1757) of the whole connection. I doubled checked it a couple times. Nonetheless I ran the code the show stuff on the LCD and it just blinks a little randomly.

1. Is something wrong with the LCD? I messed the soldering?
2. Is there a possibility of my connections being wrong?
3. Could the trimpot be the wrong way in? (I tried both ways)

Could you help me narrow this down please?

[image: LCD connected to Raspberry Pi]

Comment: This sounds like a bad LCD... (to me, at least)

Comment: @anorton ah, yea I'm a completely newbie here. If you think that is it then I will probably have to wait a day or so and try with a newer LCD :'(

Comment: Well... wait for another opinion first--I'm a complete newbie, too, to RasPi, but I do have experience with dying hardware... :)

Comment: you could try connecting VO to 5.0v directly, this should give you the lowest brightness and you should see all the boxes...

Comment: Quick check: Do you have the 3 Volt or the 5 Volt version of the LCD? The [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/GDM1602K-Extended.pdf) indicates that both types exist.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh From my order history I can see I had bought the 5V version. And I am supplying it with 5V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bad LCD. You can try resoldering your connections to the LCD, they look poorly done. The joints should look like this: 
http://smartduino.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/SMRTM501.jpg

See this guide for troubleshooting bad solder joints: 
http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/common-problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I realized only while soldering that my soldering iron tip was just too bit for something like this. Half the time I ended up soldering two tips together. I'll get one of those fine tipped soldering irons and try again.